# Merge multiple ImageView to form a heart shape

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-shape

How can I get this shape merged images?

[image]

I  have about 60 `ImageView`, I want to merge them to form the above shape with each `ImageView` with different color. I have tried to create it using `ImageView` with combination of `relative` and `linear layout` but I do not get exactly expected output.

**1.** Is this the right way to achieve it?
**2.** If yes where do I get it wrong , and if not right which one is right way to work with it?
How can I achieve it?

This is what I have done:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear7"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear7"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear7"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/red_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/red_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear7"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        />
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear7"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="110dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear7"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear7"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView14"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView13"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="130dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear7"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView15"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView16"
       />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="140dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear9"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear8"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView17"
         />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView18"
     />
       </>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear9"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView19"
            />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView20"
      />
      </>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="160dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear11"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear10"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView21"
          />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView22"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="170dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear12"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear11"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView23"
       />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView24"
       />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="180dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear13"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear12"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView25"
       />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView26"
       />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="190dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear14"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear13"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/red_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView27" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/red_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView28"
        />
             </>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear15"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear14"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView29"

         />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView30"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="210dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="210dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear16"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear15"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView31"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView32"
         />
             </>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="220dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear17"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear16"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView33"

        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView134"
         />
          </>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="230dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear18"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear17"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView35"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView36"
         />
           </>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="240dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear19"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear18"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView37"
       />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView38"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="250dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear20"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear19"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView39"
       />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView40"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="260dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear21"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear20"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView41"
   />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView42"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="270dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear22"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear21"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView43"
         />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView44"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="280dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear23"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView45"
         />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView46"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="290dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear24"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear23"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView47"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView48"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="300dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear25"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear24"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/red_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView49"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/red_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView50"
         />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear27"
    android:layout_marginLeft="310dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="310dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear26"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView53"
         />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView54"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear28"
    android:layout_marginLeft="320dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="320dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear27"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView55"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView56"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear29"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear28"
    android:layout_marginLeft="330dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="330dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView57"  />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView58"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear30"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear29"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="350dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="350dp"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView59"

        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView60"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear26"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear25"
    android:layout_marginLeft="360dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="360dp"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView51"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/green_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView52"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear31"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear30"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageView61"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: A better way to create your own custom view and achieve this using onDraw method

Comment: @ZahoorSaleem how to use such onDraw method, even link if is available so that i can get picture on what you are trying to help

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/05/draw-path-of-polygon-on-canvas-of.html ,     https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/androiddev/tree/master/ShapeFinger

Comment: @ZahoorSaleem thank you so much , let me try this then i will let You know